# Giving $m$ objects to $n$ people

Tags: combinatorics

**EXAMPLE:** $3$ people are in a table and $6$ books are thrown in it. The first person, who payed the least of the three, gets $1$ book. The second, who payed the triple of the first, gets $3$ books. The third gets $2$ books.

With this example, the list $S$ of amounts obtained by  the people would be $[1,3,2]$

This set tells a lot of information about the situation. The length of the list tells us the number of people there are, $n=3$, and adding all the numbers in the list gives us the total number of objects, $m=6$.

The list $S=[a_1,a_2,…,a_{n-1},a_n]$, which consists of nonnegative integers only, tells us how many books each person is going to have. So, if $S=[2,1,3,1]$ we know that there are $4$ people, $7$ books the $1$st person takes $2$ books, the $2$nd $1$, the $3$rd $3$ and the $4$th $1$

> My question is, knowing the list $L$ and a collection of $m$ distinct objects, how can I calculate the number of
>   different ways to give those objects to $n$ people?

By hand and using brute force, I calculated that the answers for the lists $[1,1],[2,1],[2,2],[3,2]$ are $2,3,6$ and $10$ respectively, but I can't find a generalized form. 
For lists with just one element, the answer is $1$.

Comment: You mean list of numbers, not sets, since you are allowing the same number more than once, and since you are distinguishing lists by the order of their numbers (there is a first, second,... number). Also your question is not very clear about what you are counting; the books and the people are all being distinguished?

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen Thanks! Didn't know that. I'm counting the different ways to give people the books. Actually, 1 person can have more than 1 book, but a book is just a book, what do you mean by different? I don't think that's important, but I would say yes, they are different. I think this clarifies it more. BTW: Would you mind, please, editing question in order not to get confused?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are counting the way to attribute each of $m$ different books to one of $n$ (distinguished) persons, with the restriction that they respectively get $a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n$ books (where one must of course have $a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_n=m$). That number is known as the [multinomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_coefficient) $\binom m{a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n}$. Various formulae are known for them, the easiest to remember is probably
$$
  \binom m{a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n}=\frac{m!}{a_1!a_2!\ldots a_n!}.
$$

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for. I knew it has something to do with binomial coefficients!